# Adobe Acrobat Pro not utilizing all resources during OCR - Is this normal?

Tags: resources, ocr, acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Ver 20.012.20048.6926 and I often have to OCR huge documents (1000+ pages) and it takes a LONG time to finish (over an hour easily).  This is on Win10, i5-4750 CPU, with 16GB of RAM.

During OCR, I can see that only 20% of CPU performance is being used, and only about 1GB of RAM, and it will never go higher.  This seem very strange to me, and I would hate to miss out on any extra performance I could be having since it takes so long.

Is this normal?

I also work for a large organization, so if this is NOT normal, could it be that the application is only allocated a particular amount of resources by my IT dept?

Answer (score 1):

I have since tried this on other devices, and on other networks, with the same results. After some digging around on the internet, others have noticed the same.  It seems that Adobe just isn't well optimized for multithreaded performance?

I have found other software that is, and it has reduced my time significantly as it will max out all cores 100%.  https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-tools

This is not an ad, just trying to give an answer and a better option. Cheers.